# SQL: Way to return multiple values given a date?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write SQL code that will filter based off of the remaining (inclusive) months in a quarter given a date. For example, it's currently February, so the month values that should be returned are 2 and 3. Right now I'm manually changing the values for what months are remaining and I'd love for that to just happen automatically based on what the current date is.

In one of my tables, I have a column that keeps track of dates for different events. What I'm trying to do is filter all of those events to just return the events that would happen in the currently quarter. Ideally, this filtering would happen automatically by looking at the current month and recognizing what months make up the remaining quarter and filtering the results to those months.

Code-wise, I currently have:

```
WHERE MONTH(EventDate) in (2,3)
```

I'm manually changing that `(2,3)` bit each month to update it to whatever months are left in the quarter. But what I'd love to have is something more similar to:

```
WHERE CASE
WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 1 THEN MONTH(EventDate) in (1,2,3)
WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 2 THEN MONTH(EventDate) in (2,3)
WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 3 THEN MONTH(EventDate) in (3)
... 
END
```

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) I don't really follow the logic you want to implement.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "tag with the database you are using". I'll try to update the question to make the logic clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use arithmetic to get the same quarter:

```
where ceiling(month(getdate()) / 3.0) = ceiling(month(datecol) / 3.0)
```

You can get remaining months using inequality:

```
where ceiling(month(getdate()) / 3.0) = ceiling(month(datecol) / 3.0) and
      month(getdate()) >= month(datecol)
```

Of course, you probably want to take the year into account, but your question does not mention that.

Comment: When I do `ceiling(month(getdate()) / 3)`, I'm getting 0 back. I assume it has something to do with not reading 2/3 correctly?

Comment: Fixed: just needed to convert it to a float.

Comment: @AaronKlingensmith . . . Or just use `3.0` instead of `3`.

Comment: Nothing like a painfully obvious observation to bring you down a few notches, haha. Thanks for the tip! D'oh!